# Comparing duplicate values and dropping base on a LIKE

Tags: sql, distinct, sql-like

Here's a good one.

I am almost done but hit a snag. I am trying to combine two fields then compare the data using a LIKE statement. That was the easy part. As you see in the example I now have multiple FullName with multiple CardNumbers.  I need to keep the unique FullName but if there is a duplicate only keep the one with starts with '23'. So at the bottom ZUNIGA RAMIREZ JOSE ANTONIO has 2 records and I only want to keep '230803'.  But VELAZQUEZ MARTINEZ YAZMIN only has one record that start with a '21'and I would like to keep it too.

Hope I was clear.

```
SELECT Distinct 
   [Lastname]+' '+[Firstname] as FullName
  ,[CardNumber]
  ,[Status]
  FROM [AxiomData].[dbo].[vwCardholders]
  Where [Status] > 0 AND [CardNumber] LIKE '2%'
  ORDER BY FullName ASC;
```

Example:

```
FullName                      CardNumber
SOTO SOSA HUGO                  205962
SOTO SOSA HUGO                  234429
TELLO MACIAS ALEJANDRO          230841
TORRES PONCE IVAN               234346
TORRES PONCE IVAN               205889
TRUJILLO ARCE ALBERTO           234337
TRUJILLO ARCE ALBERTO           205881
VALDIVIA HERNANDEZ BENJAMIN     230830
VARGAS ANAYA JHONATAN           205853
VAZQUEZ CALDERON MARICARMEN     205838
VAZQUEZ CALDERON MARICARMEN     234289
VAZQUEZ PINEDA PAUL             234253
VAZQUEZ PINEDA PAUL             205805
VELAZQUEZ MARTINEZ YAZMIN       210165
VILLAFUERTE MEJIA EMMANUEL      234169
VILLAFUERTE MEJIA EMMANUEL      205731
VILLAGOMEZ MAYA PEDRO           234166
YAÑEZ ESTRADA GERARDO VALENTIN  205709
ZUÑIGA RAMIREZ JOSE ANTONIO     230803
ZUÑIGA RAMIREZ JOSE ANTONIO     209588
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with conditional aggregation . . . a long conditional:

```
SELECT [Lastname]+' '+[Firstname] as FullName, 
       (case when sum(case when CardNumber like '23%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when CardNumber like '23%' then CardNumber end)
             else max(CardNumber)
        end) as CardNumber
FROM [AxiomData].[dbo].[vwCardholders]
Where [Status] > 0 AND [CardNumber] LIKE '2%'
GROUP BY [Lastname]+' '+[Firstname]
ORDER BY FullName ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!!! That worked perfect.  I have never used a conditional aggregation but will keep this example. Thanks again.

Comment: So @GordonLinoff, if I needed a range from '23' to '25' how would that change the conditional? I tried changing max to '25' but returned a lot of NULL data in the CardNumber column.

Comment: So @Gordon Linoff, if I needed a range from '23' to '25' how would that change the conditional? I tried changing max to '25' but returned a lot of NULL data in the CardNumber column.

Comment: You can use `CardNumber >= '23' and CardNumber < '26'`.  Or `left(CardNumber, 2) in ('23', '24', '25')`.